# 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 210

Tags: python

учусь работать с excel \ json файлами.

написал вот такой код:

```
import json
import openpyxl

with open ('movies.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
print(data)
```

получил ошибку:

```
Возникло исключение: UnicodeDecodeError
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 210: character maps to <undefined>
  File "D:\FILES\Programming\Python\study_python\Parsing\excel\Openpyxl\study_json.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.load(file)
```

не понимаю как ее решить

библиотека **json** идет с python . **openpyxl** усталновил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Скорей всего проблема с кодировкой в файле. Сделайте так

```py
import json
import openpyxl

with open ('movies.json', encoding="utf8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
print(data)
```

И не плохо было бы иметь что содержится в самом файле. JSON должен быть корректным. Например, одинарные кавычки в JSON не используются.

Добавлю что `0x98` - это символ тильды `~`.

Comment: Благодярю за ответ. Оказалась ошибка в JSON файле. Этот JSON взят отсюда - https://github.com/erik-sytnyk/movies-list/blob/master/db.json При копирование он был частично переведен переводчиком (расширение в браузере). Оказалось просто синтаксическая ошибка. Спасибо еще раз за помощь.

Comment: @CHeckPOint на здоровье! Обратите внимание на данную тему [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). "Спасибо" на stackoverflow говорить не принято =)